# How to retrieve last edited contact from ContactsProvider

Tags: android

I have to display new contact added or contact edited. I am able to get newly added contact but, I am not getting  last edited contact. I tried to retrieve edited contact on the basis of CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,  but if we are making any call then CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP of called contact is getting modified in ContactsProvider and thus its returning me last called contact as last edited contact. I have written query as given below:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, you should use ContactsContract.Contacts._ID like

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " DESC LIMIT 1");
```